# Serialize complex object with JSON module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python object which contains a list of other python objects which in turn contain array of another object. Simple representation:

```
class FirstClass:
    objects_list = [] #list of instances of the Second Class
    def __init__(self, objects_list: list):
        self.objects_list = objects_list

#-----------------------------------

class SecondClass:
    another_objects_list = [] #list of the ThirdClass instances
    def __init__(self, another_objects_list: list):
        self.another_objects_list = another_objects_list

#------------------------------------

class ThirdClass:
    v = ""
```

I need to serialize the `FirstClass` and all its members, including the members of the `SecondClass` and `ThirdClass` classes. Unfortunately I have to do it with the built in `json` module which doesn't serialize custom complex object by itself. I know I can serialize simple class with `json.dumps(object.__dic__)`, but I have no idea how to get it working in my case.
I tried this but it didn't work:

```
json.dumps(object.__dict__, default=[lambda e: e.__dict__
                                        for e in object.nested_objects], indent=4)
```

Comment: You could try using modules like pickle https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

Comment: Does it support JSON serialization?